# How to set dynamic value as a key to json string in request

Tags: karate

In the below JSON request: value for "paid"  is dynamically generated. When I try to pass the value to JSON string attribute, instead of dynamic value to replace "paid" it is taking "paid" as a string.

```
{
  "ENCRYP": {
    "data": "ENCRYPTED",
    "tEncryptedP": {
      "#(paid)": {
        "encryptedP": "#(parameters)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to pass a dynamic value to JSON string attribute in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to set a dynamic key using an embedded expression,

not sure if it is possible to set a new key using an embedded expression.

but you can try something like this,

```
* def paid = "PaidKey"
* def parameters = "PAID PARAMETERS"
* def enc = 
"""
{
  "ENCRYP": {
    "data": "ENCRYPTED",
    "tEncryptedP": {
    }
  }
}
"""
* def encryptedP = {"encryptedP": "#(parameters)"}
* eval enc.ENCRYP.tEncryptedP[paid] = encryptedP
```